# one sample t-tests applied to each row - 'data are essentially constant' error

Tags: t-test

I have three replicates of an experiment which gives me ratios of the abundance of different peptides.

If I take the data for one peptide:

```
pep1 <- c(4.3, 5.7, 6.3)
```

I can use a one-sample t-test to test the hypothesis that the ratio is different from 1:

```
t.test(pep1, 
       alternative=c("greater"),
       mu=1,
       paired=FALSE,
       var.equal=FALSE,
       conf.level=0.95)
```

output:

```
data:  pep1
t = 7.4818, df = 2, p-value = 0.0087
alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 3.703107      Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 5.433333
```

However if I try and apply this to the rows of a dataframe called `peptides`, where each row is a separate peptide, with three ratios:

```
t_test <- function(x) p_val =  t.test(x, 
                                      alternative=c("greater"),
                                      mu=1,
                                      paired=FALSE,
                                      var.equal=FALSE,
                                      conf.level=0.95)$p.value

apply(peptides, 1, t_test)
```

I get the `data are essentially constant` error.

I don't understand! I think apply is doing what I want because if I substitute 't-test' for 'mean' then it does the correct calculations.

My aim is to get the p-values for each peptide and then adjust these for multiple comparisons.

I'm relatively new to R, and any advice would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem in my data - There's one peptide where the ratios are identical in the three replicates. Of course this then means that it's not possible to estimate confidence intervals and perform t-tests. Removing this value allows the code to run fine.

Many thanks to everyone who's had a look at the problem.